# React Native image cropping with multi picker and permission handling

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an application that is based on image processing. I need to select multiple images from the picker at the same time and show them in the view container, where first it will ask for permission then pick images from the gallery or camera. I also need a cropping feature in it to crop the image. Something like the utility class of image selection supports all the options needed for the application. I'm using the following code

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    image: Images.placeholderImage
  }

  onPress = () => {
    // Here goes the picker code
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Image source={this.state.image} style={{width:200, height:200}}/> 
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text>Select Image</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Simulator > Device > Erase All Content and Settings

worked for me in iOS